# The toggling methods of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, toggle

I have browsed several tutorial sites to get more information about this, but I have not found any which focuses on this topic.

Apart from jQuery hide/show, jQuery fade and jQuery slide are there any other toggling methods in jQuery?

Comment: Why not check the [jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)?

Comment: You can have a brief description and elaborative example for each here as well: [w3school-jQuery Effect Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_effects.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course there are few more methods like-

1. slideDown()
2. slideUp()
3. addClass()
4. removeClass()
5. toggleCLass()

please refer the official website .
https://api.jquery.com